# JavaFX WebView: custom cursors not working?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I tried to get css custom cursors to work with Java WebView within a tag, to no avail.

For example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        String cursorUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_top_right.svg/36px-Pixel_51_icon_cursor_click_top_right.svg.png";
        String content = String.format("<body style=cursor: url('%s'), auto;>", cursorUrl);
        content = content + "<br>some text<br> a link: http://google.com </body>";
        System.out.println(content);
        webView.getEngine().loadContent(content);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 960, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

which just shows the regular cursor.

I also tried to replace the .png cursor by a .cur file, as well as remove the quotes around the url. Nothing seems to work.

Does WebView not support the feature? Other cursor such as `wait` and `grab` work fine.

Comment: The useragent might not support that feature. You can print the useragent and search the web for the capabilities of that specific agent and version.

Comment: User agent is `Mozilla/5.0` (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) `AppleWebKit/605.1` (KHTML, like Gecko) `JavaFX/10` `Safari/605.1`

Answer (score 0):

It was a mere problem related to quotes.

I changed the content line to

```java
String content = String.format("<body style=\"cursor: url('%s') 10 10, auto\";>", cursorUrl);
```

and it worked fine.